# Finding the first non-zero terms in the Taylor series of $x^4\sin(4x)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> Find the first four nonzero terms of the Taylor series about 0 for the function

$$f(x) = x^4\sin(4x)$$

> Note that you may want to find these in a manner other than by direct differentiation of the function.

I am honestly lost. My initial instinct is to just start taking a bunch of derivatives, but I know that there has got to be a better way of doing it. I was reading in my textbook about substitution, but I am not sure how this applies here.
Thanks in advance. Any sort of direction would be greatly appreciated here.

Comment: You could just plug in the Taylor series for $\sin 4x$...

Comment: Note that $0$ is a zero of $f(x)$ with multiplicity atleast $4$, so $0$ is also a zero of atleast the first three derivatives of $f$, i.e. $f(x)=x^4(f^{(4)}(0)/4!+xf^{(5)}(0)/5!+...)$ and thus $f(x)/x^4=\sin 4x=(f^{(4)}(0)/4!+xf^{(5)}(0)/5!+...)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the Taylor expansion of $\sin(y)$ is

$$\sin(y) = y  - \frac{y^3}{3!} + \frac{y^5}{5!} - \frac{y^7}{7!} + \mathcal{O}(y^9)$$

Now substitute $y=4x$ and multiply by $x^4$. You will get

$$x^4 \sin(4x) = 4x^5 - \frac{4^3}{3!}x^7 + \frac{4^5}{5!}x^9 - \frac{4^7}{7!}x^{11} + \mathcal{O}(x^{13})$$